# How to configure elasticsearch.yml and enterprise-search.yml when not hosted on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, deployment

I want to host Elasticsearch and Enterprise Search on an AWS server. How exactly do I have to configure the `.yml` files so that it's working? Do I have to do anything different at all? The documentation is not clear about that.

Edit:

Maybe it's helpful, to show you the current configuration:

For elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
#
xpack.security.enabled: true

discovery.type: single-node

cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage: 200mb
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 500mb
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 300mb

xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled: true
```

And for enterprise-search.yml:

```
## ================= Elastic Enterprise Search Configuration ==================
#
# NOTE: Elastic Enterprise Search comes with reasonable defaults.
#       Before adjusting the configuration, make sure you understand what you
#       are trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# NOTE: For passwords, the use of environment variables is encouraged
#       to keep values from being written to disk, e.g.
#       elasticsearch.password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:changeme}
#
# ---------------------------------- Secrets ----------------------------------
#
# Encryption keys to protect your application secrets. This field is required.
#
secret_management.encryption_keys: [5322b64cf4260f9d94751a471e5921829f3b83cda9fcc9999346671c590430eb]


#
# ------------------------------- Elasticsearch -------------------------------
#
# Enterprise Search needs one-time permission to alter Elasticsearch settings.
# Ensure the Elasticsearch settings are correct, then set the following to
# true. Or, adjust Elasticsearch's config/elasticsearch.yml instead.
# See README.md for more details.
#
allow_es_settings_modification: true
#
# Elasticsearch full cluster URL:
#
#elasticsearch.host: http://127.0.0.1:9200
#
# Elasticsearch credentials:
#
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: 5gJDLZPSnl1ut8OrtUla
#
# Elasticsearch custom HTTP headers to add to each request:
#
#elasticsearch.headers:
#  X-My-Header: Contents of the header
#
# Elasticsearch SSL settings:
#
#elasticsearch.ssl.enabled: false
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate:
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority:
#elasticsearch.ssl.key:
#elasticsearch.ssl.key_passphrase:
#elasticsearch.ssl.verify: true
#
# Elasticsearch startup retry:
#
#elasticsearch.startup_retry.enabled: true
#elasticsearch.startup_retry.interval: 5 # seconds
#elasticsearch.startup_retry.fail_after: 200 # seconds
#
# ------------------------------- Hosting & Network ---------------------------
#
# Define the exposed URL at which users will reach Enterprise Search.
# Defaults to localhost:3002 for testing purposes.
# Most cases will use one of:
#
# * An IP: http://255.255.255.255
# * A FQDN: http://example.com
# * Shortname defined via /etc/hosts: http://ent-search.search
#
#ent_search.external_url: http://localhost:3002
#
# Web application listen_host and listen_port.
# Your application will run on this host and port.
#
# * ent_search.listen_host: Must be a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.
# * ent_search.listen_port: Must be a valid port number (1-65535).
#
#ent_search.listen_host: 127.0.0.1
#ent_search.listen_port: 3002
#
# ------------------------------ Authentication -------------------------------
#
# The origin of authenticated Enterprise Search users.
# Options are standard, elasticsearch-native, and elasticsearch-saml.
#
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/workplace-search-security.html
#
# * standard: Users are created within the Enterprise Search dashboard.
# * elasticsearch-native: Users are managed via the Elasticsearch native realm.
# * elasticsearch-saml: Users are managed via the Elasticsearch SAML realm.
#
ent_search.auth.source: standard
#
# (SAML only) Name of the realm within the Elasticsearch realm chain.
#
#ent_search.auth.name:
#
# ---------------------------------- Limits -----------------------------------
#
# Configurable limits for Enterprise Search.
# NOTE: Overriding the default limits can impact performance negatively.
#       Also, changing a limit here does not actually guarantee that
#       Enterprise Search will work as expected as related Elasticsearch limits
#       can be exceeded.
#
#### Workplace Search
#
# Configure the maximum allowed document size for Custom API Sources.
#
#workplace_search.custom_api_source.document_size.limit: 100kb
#
# Configure how many fields a Custom API Source can have.
# NOTE: The Elasticsearch/Lucene setting `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`
# might also need to be adjusted if "Max clause count exceeded" errors start
# occurring. See more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html
#
#workplace_search.custom_api_source.total_fields.limit: 64
#
#### App Search
#
# Configure the maximum allowed document size.
#
#app_search.engine.document_size.limit: 100kb
#
# Configure how many fields an engine can have.
# NOTE: The Elasticsearch/Lucene setting `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`
# might also need to be adjusted if "Max clause count exceeded" errors start
# occurring. See more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html
#
#app_search.engine.total_fields.limit: 64
#
# Configure how many source engines a meta engine can have.
#
#app_search.engine.source_engines_per_meta_engine.limit: 15
#
# Configure how many facet values can be returned by a search.
#
#app_search.engine.total_facet_values_returned.limit: 250
#
# Configure how big full-text queries are allowed.
# NOTE: The Elasticsearch/Lucene setting `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`
# might also need to be adjusted if "Max clause count exceeded" errors start
# occurring. See more here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html
#
#app_search.engine.query.limit: 128
#
# Configure total number of synonym sets an engine can have.
#
#app_search.engine.synonyms.sets.limit: 256
#
# Configure total number of terms a synonym set can have.
#
#app_search.engine.synonyms.terms_per_set.limit: 32
#
# Configure how many analytics tags can be associated with a single query or clickthrough.
#
#app_search.engine.analytics.total_tags.limit: 16
#
# ---------------------------------- Workers ----------------------------------
#
# Configure the number of worker threads.
#
#worker.threads: 4
#
# ----------------------------------- APIs ------------------------------------
#
# Set to true hide product version information from API responses.
#
#hide_version_info: false
#
# ---------------------------------- Mailer -----------------------------------
#
# Connect Enterprise Search to a mailer.
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/workplace-search/current/workplace-search-smtp-mailer.html
#
#email.account.enabled: false
#email.account.smtp.auth: plain
#email.account.smtp.starttls.enable: false
#email.account.smtp.host: 127.0.0.1
#email.account.smtp.port: 25
#email.account.smtp.user:
#email.account.smtp.password:
#email.account.email_defaults.from:
#
# ---------------------------------- Logging ----------------------------------
#
# Choose your log export path.
#
#log_directory: log
#
# Log level can be: debug, info, warn, error, fatal, or unknown.
#
#log_level: info
#
# Log format can be: default, json
#
#log_format: default
#
# Choose your Filebeat logs export path.
#
#filebeat_log_directory: log
#
# Enable logging app logs to stdout (enabled by default).
#
#enable_stdout_app_logging: true
#
# The number of files to keep on disk when rotating logs. When set to 0, no
# rotation will take place.
#
#log_rotation.keep_files: 7
#
# The maximum file size in bytes before rotating the log file. If
# log_rotation.keep_files is set to 0, no rotation will take place and there
# will be no size limit for the singular log file.
#
#log_rotation.rotate_every_bytes: 1048576 # 1 MiB
#
# ---------------------------------- TLS/SSL ----------------------------------
#
# Configure TLS/SSL encryption.
#
#ent_search.ssl.enabled: false
#ent_search.ssl.keystore.path:
#ent_search.ssl.keystore.password:
#ent_search.ssl.keystore.key_password:
#ent_search.ssl.redirect_http_from_port:
#
# ---------------------------------- Session ----------------------------------
#
# Set a session key to persist user sessions through process restarts.
#
#secret_session_key:
#
# --------------------------------- Telemetry ---------------------------------
#
# Reporting your basic feature usage statistics helps us improve your user
# experience. Your data is never shared with anyone.
#
# Set to false to disable telemetry capabilities entirely. You can alternatively
# opt out through the Settings page.
#
#telemetry.enabled: true
#
# If false, collection of telemetry data is disabled; however, it can be
# enabled via the Settings page if telemetry.allow_changing_opt_in_status is
# true.
#
#telemetry.opt_in: true
#
# If true, users are able to change the telemetry setting at a later time
# through the Settings page. If false, the value of telemetry.opt_in determines
# whether to send telemetry data or not.
#
#telemetry.allow_changing_opt_in_status: true
#
# ----------------------------- Diagnostics report ----------------------------
#
# Path where diagnostic reports will be generated.
#
#diagnostic_report_directory: diagnostics
#
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS has its own version

See this https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/